# PHP Tidy class not found, error

Tags: php, tidy, htmltidy, php-ini

I was writing some code for repair html string.
I read some nice solutions which work with the Tidy PHP class but I had some troubles with it.
What in this post is written, is exactly what I want but I need to install / load the *PHP Tidy class*.
[Close tags from a truncated HTML string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008333/close-tags-from-a-truncated-html-string)

I'm working on `PHP 5.5.4`.
I tried to install tidy following some tutorials but nothing has append.
When I call the tidy class `$tidi = new \tidy();`, NetBeans suggests me the class and clicking on it (Ctrl + click) I see it but refreshing the page I obtain the error `Class 'tidy' not found in ... /myfile.php line ...`

I used in the same way the class `$myVar = new \DomDocument();` but it works perfectly.

Checking whether the Tidy extension is loaded like below, I get "NOT LOADED".

```
echo extension_loaded('tidy') ? "LOADED" : "NOT LOADED";
```

Please, can someone explain me how Tidy works and how can I set it up?
My *Ubuntu*'s version is *13.10*.

Comment: Did you enable the extension in your php.ini file? Does your extensions folder contain the necessary extension? What kind of PHP environment are you running (Xampp, loacl apache, LAMP server...)?

Comment: I tried to enable it but i didn't understand very well how i can do it. Can you explain me what i have to enable and how can i include the extension?
I installed LAMP server separately. thanks for the quick response

Comment: I ran into this because the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/tidy.installation.php) misleadingly say "This extension is bundled with PHP 5 and greater, and is installed using the --with-tidy configure option." and I believed them. I had to do a yum install as the answers below allude to.

Answer (score 10):

Your php.ini contains a list of "extension=somefile.so" lines. You are missing the correct line for your tidy extension. It should be included but commented in your file. Just remove the ; character in front of the one line for the tidy extension and restart your webserver.

Sample for windows:

```
extension=php_tidy.dll
```

Sample for Linux:

```
extension=tidy.so
```

On some Linux distribution, it has to be installed if you can't find the extension file `tidy.so` in your extensions folder. Execute the correct line depending on your distribution. You have to be root or use sudo:

CentOS/RedHat (replace with correct lib as found via `yum search php-tidy`:

```
yum install rh-php56-php-tidy.x86_64
```

Debian/Ubuntu:

```
apt-get install php5-tidy
```

Comment: Thank you very much but nothing is working yet.
Then, i tried simply adding `extension=tidy.so` to the _/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini_ and, restarting apache nothing is happened. After that i prompted a _locate tidy.so_ and it gave _/usr/lib/libtidy.so_. Then i set `extension_dir = "/usr/lib"` but nothing is still happened.
If i launch `sudo apt-get install php5-tidy` i have an error

Comment: Don't change the extensions folder. What distribution are you using? Did you get any startup errors when just enabling the so?

Comment: It should be :   yum install rh-php56-php-tidy.x86_64

Comment: @DylanB Updated.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and I finnally figured it out, this solution is for ubuntu 14.04 running xampp.

step 1 
open terminal and input the following

```
sudo apt-get install php5-tidy
```

step 2
    
 time to find out where "tidy.so" got installed to.

for me it was installed to "/usr/lib/php5/20121212/tidy.so"

step 3

find and open your php.ini file and find the extensions section and insert the following line

```
extension=/usr/lib/php5/20121212/tidy.so
```

step 4

go back to your terminal and run the following to restart your server.

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart
```

step 5

verifying that the new tidy module has been loaded by either

in terminal

```
php -m
```

and/or by creating a file on your server in the htdocs called test.php and inserting the following code

```
<?php echo extension_loaded('tidy') ? "LOADED" : "NOT LOADED"; ?>
```

next run that test.php file in your browser and it should read "LOADED"

if not go back and review the previous steps until you get that message.

I hope this helps, :)